# Azure and DNS services

Tags: azure, dns

I have a `Virtual network` (MyVPN) resource in Azure, being a class C network, MyVPN has `Azure provided DNS service` as DNS servers, so all virtual machines with a NIC connected to this network are able to resolve their hostname successfully, for example virtual machine `myvm01` can ssh to `myvm02` using only the hostname instead of IP.

However, they are unable to make a reverse DNS lookup, which makes sense since by default Azure does not provide a `reverse DNS lookup zone`. [By following Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-reverse-dns-hosting) I managed to create it, sadly I don't really know if I should delegate to `Azure provided DNS service` and if so, how to do it (I tried [following this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns))

What should I do now to allow `myvm01` be able to resolve the IP of `myvm02` to its hostname?

Answer (score 1):

There is [another manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-reverse-dns-for-azure-services) for enabling reverse lookup DNS in azure.

> **Will my reverse DNS records resolve from the internet?**
>
> Yes. Once you set the reverse DNS property for your Azure service,
> Azure manages all the DNS delegations and DNS zones required to ensure
> that reverse DNS record resolves for all Internet users.
>
> **Are default reverse DNS records created for my Azure services?**
>
> No. Reverse DNS is an opt-in feature. No default reverse DNS records
> are created if you choose not to configure them.

It seems that reverse dns has to be enabled if it is used internally.